# Decoding String list in python from a binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-data, non-ascii-characters

I need to read a list of strings from a binary file and create a python list.

I'm using the below command to extract data from binary file:

```
tmp = f.read(100) 
abc, = struct.unpack('100c',tmp)
```

The data that I can see in variable 'abc' is exactly as shown below, but I need to get the below data into a python list as strings.

Data that I need as a list: 'UsrVal' 'VdetHC' 'VcupHC' ..... 'Gravity_Axis'

```
b'UsrVal\x00VdetHC\x00VcupHC\x00VdirHC\x00HdirHC\x00UpFlwHC\x00UxHC\x00UyHC\x00UzHC\x00VresHC\x00UxRP\x00UyRP\x00UzRP\x00VresRP\x00Gravity_Axis'
```

Comment: I have just been doing something similar and I used the command line package `strings`, which worked a treat.

Comment: You're halfway there, you just need to split the bytes

Comment: Did you not try the obvious? `abc.split(b'\x00')`?

Comment: When I tried, abc.split(b'\x00'), I get the values with 'b' infront, like b'Usrval, b'VdetHC etc... How to remove that 'b', please excuse me for my poor knowledge in dealing with binary files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i would suggest you to do it with one liner.

You need to decode binary string and then you can do a split based on `"\x00"` which will return the list you are looking for.

e.g

```
my_binary_out = b'UsrVal\x00VdetHC\x00VcupHC\x00VdirHC\x00HdirHC\x00UpFlwHC\x00UxHC\x00UyHC\x00UzHC\x00VresHC\x00UxRP\x00UyRP\x00UzRP\x00VresRP\x00Gravity_Axis'
decoded_list = my_binary_out.decode("latin1", 'ignore').split('\x00')
#or 
decoded_list = my_binary_out.decode("cp1252", 'ignore').split('\x00')
```

**Output** Will look like this :

```
['UsrVal', 'VdetHC', 'VcupHC', 'VdirHC', 'HdirHC', 'UpFlwHC', 'UxHC', 'UyHC', 'UzHC', 'VresHC', 'UxRP', 'UyRP', 'UzRP', 'VresRP', 'Gravity_Axis']
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm facing another issue with this piece of code, as I have the character ² (power of 2, instead of ^2, it is ² , like m/s²) in my string.

Comment: I'm facing another issue with this piece of code, as I have the character ² (power of 2, instead of ^2, it is ² , like m/s²) in my string. Now my string is: b'-\x00deg/s^2\x00m/s^2\x00m/s^2\x00rpm\x00m/s\xb2\x00m/s\xb2\x00m/s\xb2\x00m/s\xb2\x00m/s\xb2\x00m/s\xb2\x00deg'                                                                                    When I check the ord('²') it is 178, for your ref. Please help me with this.

Comment: The error message that I see is, UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 595: invalid start byte

Comment: I have fixed decode error i assume you don't want to get the decode value of  ' 0xb2' i.e `my_binary_out.decode('utf-8', 'ignore').split('\x00')` which should give you your desired values `['-', 'deg/s^2', 'm/s^2', 'm/s^2', 'rpm', 'm/s', 'm/s', 'm/s', 'm/s', 'm/s', 'm/s', 'deg']`

Comment: Accept the answer if it solves the issue to help others :)

Comment: Thanks for this, but the 6-11 values should have been m/s² or like m/s^2, is there a way to do this?

Comment: use decoder `"latin1"` will decode subscript and superscript properly. i have updated the answer or you can alternatively you can use cp1252  decoder try which ever works better for you cp1252 is a single-byte character encoding of the Latin chars

Comment: Thanks a lot, "latin1" served the purpose. I'm trying to read my entire binary file which has lot of data types, will comeback to you if I face any issues further. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @rajgary can you accept the answer if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for a quick and messy way here, AND assuming your string

> b'UsrVal\x00VdetHC\x00VcupHC\x00VdirHC\x00HdirHC\x00UpFlwHC\x00UxHC\x00UyHC\x00UzHC\x00VresHC\x00UxRP\x00UyRP\x00UzRP\x00VresRP\x00Gravity_Axis'

is in fact interpreted as

> **"** b'UsrVal\x00VdetHC\x00VcupHC\x00VdirHC\x00HdirHC\x00UpFlwHC\x00UxHC\x00UyHC\x00UzHC\x00VresHC\x00UxRP\x00UyRP\x00UzRP\x00VresRP\x00Gravity_Axis' **"**

Then the following few lines of code result with 'b' having the array you want.

```
a = {YourStringHere}
b = a[2:-1].split("\x00")
```